# Is there a seamless way to cache the file table of an HDD to prevent unnecessary spin ups?

Tags: files, filesystems, hard-disk, caching

I'd like to be able to browse the file system of my external HDD without having it spin up. Is there an easy way to cache its file table in a way that allows me to use normal tools like Caja/Gnome Files/`ls`/`cd` to navigate folders and list files without it spinning up?

Comment: Linux already does that caching. The cache just might not have been populated yet because you haven't read the relevant directories. Or, it got evicted because something else needed the memory.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about some kind of finicky kernel memory cache designed to speed up system level operations. I'd suggest that cache is not super helpful for typical user-level use cases. I don't see any reason why we couldn't have a full copy of an external drive's filesystem metadata stored in a local file.

Comment: Nothing about this is finicky.